# Android Studio Preview is blank or shows android...CoordinatorLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to Android Development, but not new into programming.

I just wanted to write my first app and created a blank project using a Navigation Drawer Activity as main Activity.

The Problem is the Preview either only shows Android...CoordinatorLayout or nothing depending on the Theme I choose.

It shows a completely blank screen if I use AppCompat as the theme and when I use AppTheme I have the Problem with Android...CoordinatorLayout in the middle of the screen.

I already tried changing the Theme to AppCompat.
I already tried to change the build.gradle implementation of AppCompat to a different version.

In the Preview I can see an Information **I** and when I click on it it says Render Problem 2 times and Missing Styles one time and there is an Error "Failed to instantiate one or more class" which reads:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:

- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  
If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener Copy stack to clipboard
```

The Stack:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:180)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:61)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:118)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(ActionBarContainer.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:481)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:264)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:222)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:209)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:337)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:348)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:248)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.<init>(BridgeActionBar.java:89)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.<init>(AppCompatActionBar.java:68)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createActionBar(Layout.java:277)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:161)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:288)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:544)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:678)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Refreshing does not do anything.

Remember this is a project just created from Android Studio itself I wrote any line of code...

I know there are many posts about this but any was able to solve my problem.

I hope someone can help me.

Btw: I am using Kotlin as developing language.

Greetings

Comment: Have you built the project yet?

Comment: What version of `android studio` and `gradle` are you using? Try to use latest versions clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: I just installed Android Studio that day so I think everything should be new.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest update android studio and plugins to latest version via clik **Help--Check for Updates**, and recreate Navigation Drawer Activity using wizard.

If still cannot see layout preview, try modify application theme like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

and add below line in AndroidManifest.xml file like this:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: I already have the latest Version of everything I changed what could be changed. Then I rebuild, but sadly nothing changed.

Comment: Oh my gosh I just reinstalled everything and now used Android 5.0 instead of 5.1, I then made the changes you said and it works! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: When I said it would work I used an empty Activity and it works with that, however, it does not work when I let Android Studio create a Navigation Drawer Activity. How to do that then?

Answer (score -1):

> Please follow this steps

```
     1- Go to your res folder and inside res folder.
            2-Go to values.
            3-Go to style.xml
            4-change  <!-- Base application theme. -->
          <style name="AppTheme"parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     to 
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: It's changed but sadly the problem still exists...

Btw. I have 2 styles.xml file one is (v21), but there is something else in it.